# How to add scope parameter to a Oauth2 token restsharp request

Tags: c#, post, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I'm trying to get a token from a given endpoint by using restsharp and client_credentials authenthication specifying a scope.
The token I get in response does not have the correct scope and the I use it in fails (no sufficient right).

When I do the request via postman Oauth2 authenthication the token I get has the correct scope.
[PostmanRequest result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w75H.png).
But when I do it like that :

```
var client = new RestClient(_tokenEndpoint);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("client_id", _clientId);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", _clientSecret);
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");

request.AddParameter("Scope", "rxpclient-arsenal-ms.write",ParameterType.GetOrPost);

IRestResponse<TokenResponse> response = client.Execute<TokenResponse>(request);
```

The response I get is [Image of restSharp response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n7uk.png)

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out "scope" with no capital letter is the solution